# Using the same input box to search different things

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which searcher's google web and another input to search google images. For each input i have buttons to fadeIn either. Can the search input be the same but search different sites?

Here is a fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/kwC36/

To search the web I use:

`<form action="http://google.com/search" method="get" class="websearch">`

and to search images I use:

`<form action="http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=" method="get" class="imagesearch">`

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) to the button so the form action can be dynamic:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="search-form" action="" method="get" class="websearch">
    <input id="search-field" type="text" class="searcher" name="" /> 
</form>

<input type="button" value="Search the web" class="search-btn" data-action="http://google.com/search" data-field-name="" />
<input type="button" value="Search images" class="search-btn" data-action="http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=" data-field-name="q" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.search-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#search-field').attr('name',$(this).data('field-name'));
    $('#search-form').attr('action',$(this).data('action')).submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. What would you do though if the search input has to be more than one? For example, to search wikipedia you need few other hidden inputs. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/kwC36/15 . Can you assign more hidden inputs with your way? Thanks

Comment: Anyway if you have multiple forms which have different variable inputs, then I wouldn't recommend this solution as it's no longer the simplest and most easily-maintainable code you could use.

Comment: A sorry mate. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zgF3s/ . To search wikipedia you need a bunch of hidden inputs. Got anything in mind for a better way of doing it? I'm doing a uni project of a around 30 search forms. Instead of each time having a different input I though it would be a good way doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can switch action on the form:

```
$('.web').click(function(){
    $('form')[0].action = "http://google.com/search";
    // do something
    $('.websearch').fadeIn();
});

$('.image').click(function(){
    $('form')[0].action = "http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=";
    // do something
    $('.websearch').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It seems pretty straight forward. My question though is, what would I need to do if the action or input is different that the images and the web search. Can you take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kwC36/15/ . For wikipedia search, you need more than just 1 input which are hidden. Is it possible again to use the same input? Thanks sir

Comment: Your fiddle returns a 404. Is there a typo in the URL?

Comment: Sorry yes. http://jsfiddle.net/zgF3s/ here it is. Check the HTML. To search wikipedia you need a bunch of hidden inputs

Comment: You can use the same input box as your your search term input box. The hidden fields are query params I suppose? In that case, you just need to append their values while forming your URL. Makes sense>

Comment: If you can post what your expected output is, I can quickly put up some example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="srch_images" value="Search Images">
<input type="submit" name="srch_google" value="Search Google">


if( isset($_POST['srch_images'] )
{
     something();
}
else if( isset($_POST['srch_google']) )
{
     something_else();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same textbox to search for web and image. Also there is no need to have two form tags. Try this

```
$('.web').click(function(){
    $('form').attr('action', "http://google.com/search").submit();

});

$('.image').click(function(){
    $('form').attr('action', "http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=").submit();

});
```

Comment: I like the concept of this but it doesn't seem to be fading in.

Comment: What do you want to fadeIn? I guess when you click on the button you would want to perform the search, right?

Comment: If you want you can keep your fadeIn code it will work but when would you perform the search(submit the form)?

Comment: No I meant literally fadeIn the input

Comment: On which event will you perform the search?

Comment: See, if you want I can just leave your line in my answer to show the fadeIn effect for textbox but my question is when will you perform the search?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://google.com/search" method="get" class="websearch">
    <input type="text" class="searcher">
    <input type="submit" value="Web Search" class="web">
    <input type="submit" value="Image Search" class="image">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
        .attr('action', 'http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=');
});
```

That should do it.